# How to construct a path back to server in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jsp that does an ajax call and calls a javascript file on success. In this file I want to create another jquery ajax call back to the server.

Am I on the server when this file is processing or in the browser?
How do I create the equivalent of ${pageContext.request.contextPath} in this file.

I tried to re-use the call I already have but have realised that the path I am using does not make the call to the servlet as it relies on the context above. There must be a way to do this.

[edit] It seems that I can use either the Window or Document objects to construct the path back to the server.

Comment: "Am I on the server (..) or in the browser", If you don't know that, it's probably time to pick up a book on general web development ?

Comment: well I know the jsp is on the server what I mean is is the javascript file processed before or after the response goes back. The point of ajax was to connect to the server from the client. Thats the bit I am unsure of.

Comment: The javascript is processed after the serverside code, then at any you can make an ajax request, which is a HTTP request just like loading a page in the browser, but without leaving the current page, it returns the result to the ajax callback instead.

Comment: @adeno thanks so are there any methods available to construct that http path or do I have to just hard code it in there?

Comment: Don't really know Java, so I have no idea how you'd do it specifically, but hardcoding a URL to whatever script you'd like to execute is not uncommon in other languages.

Comment: Actually it looks like I can do what I want with window.location.href.replace("bit to replace", " replace with") that should get me what I need.